# Find points on linear line equidistant from third point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out where the two points on a line defined by $y = 2x + 1$ would be from a third point at $(-1,3)$ and $4$ units from that point to the line. I've deduced that I maybe need a perpendicular line to $y = 2x + 1$, which is $y = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{2}$. This produces an intersect of the two equations at the point $(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{11}{5})$. From there I've tried to use the Pythagorean in various ways, but they've all produced huge messes. The visual graph looks like one of the points would be at $(-1,-1)$ on the $y = 2x + 1$ line, but, as I say, I can't seem to figure out how to get there.

Comment: Your points are the intersection of the line with a circle of radius 4 centered at your point. You can easily write the equation of the circle and solve the system.

Comment: @GReyes In fact we only need to solve a single equation, as we can choose a coordinate system where one axis is parallel to the line and the other one is orthogonal to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your (affine) line is given by $(1,2)t+(0,1)$. The projection of $(-1,3)$ onto that line is given by $(3/5,11/5)$ as you said.

Now the square total distance of any point on the line is given by the square distance of to this projection plus the square distance from $(-1,3)$ to $(3/5,11/5)$.
So for any $P$ on the line we have
$$ ||P-(-1,3)||^2 = ||P-(3/5,11/5)||^2+16/5 $$
Now as
$$(3/5,11/5) = (0,1) + (1,2)3/5$$
and if
$$ P = (0,1)+(1,2)t$$
then
$$ ||P-(3/5,11/5)||^2 = (t-3/5)^2 || (1,2)||^2 =  (t-3/5)^2 \cdot 5$$
Thus we want to solve
$$ 4^2 = 16 = 16/5 + (t-3/5)^2\cdot 5 $$
for $t$. Thus we get
$$ (t-3/5)^2 = \frac{16(4/5)}5 = 64/25$$
thus
$$ t-3/5 = \pm 8/5$$
thus
$$ t_{1,2} = 11/5, -1$$

So we get the two points
$$ x_1  = (0,1)+(1,2)\cdot 11/5 = (11/5,27/5)$$
$$ x_2 = (0,1)+(1,2)\cdot (-1) = (-1,-1)$$

Comment: Could you point me to an affine space/line tutorial? I take it there's some sort of parametrization at work here.